# JavaScript in PDF: TextField onAction Listener

Tags: javascript, pdf, events, listener, event-listener

How can I achieve an event-call in JavaScript by the PDF when you hit enter on a specific TextField? (alternatively: on every key stroke in that specific TextField)

I've tried

```
this.getField("field1").addEventListener('input', myMethod);
```

and

```
this.getField("field1").events.add(
{
    onEveryEvent: function()
    {
        myMethod();
    }
});
```

but they both do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (as described [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_AcrobatForms%2FSetting_Acrobat_form_field_properties.htm%23IX_setting_an_action_2)):

First you have to set a partial name for the field with the `PDField.setPartialName(String name)`-method, for example `myField.setPartialName("myField1");`. Then you can access the field via JavaScript in the PDF.

Now use the `setAction(..., ...)`-method to set your action/event/listener. For example: `this.getField("myField1").setAction("Validate", "myMethod()");`

Please notice how the second argument is indeed a string and not a method. Also: `"Validate"` is not just a name and probably only one of many action/event-strings. Unfortunately I do not know what those other strings are. `"Validate"` is from the docs example and triggers (at least) when

- the field loses focus and has changed value in the last focus
- you change its value and press enter

Comment: Sounds like you found the answer yourself, but to answer what other action/events you can pass to .setAction(), what you need is the "Javascript for Acrobat API Reference". Find it here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html